# Separador de miles mvc

Tags: c#, mvc, model-view-controller

Quiero usar el separador de miles, el inconveniente es que el valor sale así:

**17,000**

Y yo quiero que se vea así:

**17.000**

Es decir, lo que quiero es que en vez de la **coma (,)** se vea el **punto (.)**

Estoy usando esto en la clase:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
public Nullable<double> valorUno { get; set; }
```

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Segun yo tengo entendido eso viene en las configuraciones de region e idioma de la computadora

Comment: Mostrar el formato de la info es trabajo de la vista no del modelo, es mejor que trabajes con estilos en tu vista, asi como el uso de los correctos controles ejemplo usas un input tipo numeric para html y el formato lo da una definicion de su clase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A parte de lo que dijo Ivan-San, en la documentacion sobre formatear los numer puedes configurar tu propia regla. Por ejemplo:

```
{0:#.##}
```

Aguí te dejo un [enlace a la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierPt) donde se explica como se haría.

Comment: De hecho, ya estuve probando lo que mencionas pero al momento de visualizarlo se ve así (con tu ejemplo, claro): `17000`, pero si cambio a `{0:#,##}` se ve `17,000`

Comment: Y despues del lado del cliente dejaras que see modifique la cantidad ?

Comment: Ya intentaste probando con números que llevan mas de 1 sola coma, por ejemplo 1,000,000,000? El formato que estas usando es para separar creo decimales, no miles...

Comment: Si este enlce deja de ser disponible significa que Microsoft ya no existe y este sitio no va tener ningun sentido

Comment: @TomaszVizaint los enlaces a la documentación de Microsoft han cambiado numerosas veces a lo largo del tiempo sin que Microsoft deje de existir. Sería interesante que añadieras las partes clave de la página enlazada en la propia respuesta (manteniendo el enlace como referencia). Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información y para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Stackoverflow existe por que segun los datos cientifocos 70% de la poblacion no sabe leer, pensar y por lo suigiente buscar, prefiere que otros hacen trabajo por ellos en vez de descubrir por si mismo el problema, en las paginas com estas hay escaso la situcion cuando con el codigo alguien explica su logica, simplemente pega una solucion y si el receptor lo copia y pega en su programa y que esta solucion funciona, bien, si no, busca excusas  hasta alguien acierta.  El mensaje a que conteste ya no existe, por que, que lo escibio lo borro, asi de que me estas hablando.

Answer (score 2):

Usualmente los lenguajes de programación utilizan las características de idioma y regionales del PC donde se ejecutan. De modo que imprimir un valor en un PC con configuración de España produciría probablemente algo como:

**100,00 €**

Pero si el mismo valor se intentara imprimir en un PC con configuración de EEUU probablemente ser obtendría lo siguiente:

**$100.00**

No es un tema de como utilizar la mascara de formato de valores, la cual independiente de la región o configuración siempre se debe utilizar de la misma forma, no es válido pasar de **{0:#,##0.00}** a **{0:#.##0,00}** esto no tiene ningún efecto sobre como se imprima el valor, lo único que hace es causar problemas.

En C# al igual que otros lenguajes es posible personalizar la configuración regional de modo que se ignore la del PC y siempre los valores numéricos manejen el mismo formato al momento de ser impresos. Acá te dejo un ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace sharpPower
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 100;
            CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", us));

            CultureInfo es = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", es));
        }
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo leer un poco más en la [página de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting-in-dotnet-framework)

Answer (score 2):

Mi recomendación sería utilizar otra propiedad y le das el formato que necesitas. 
Utilizando el método de [**String.Format**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1)  
Especificamos que utilice la interfaz de [IFormatProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.8) 
Y para tu caso en especial usamos el formato `es-ES` *(Español(España))* debido a que ellos separan los *decimales* por **,** y los *miles* por **.**

Lista con todos los formatos [**CultureInfo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HUzcVx)

```
public string valorUno_miles => string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"), "{0:N2}", valorUno);
```